# Adding Shiki code highlighter to remark and rehype

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, markdown

I am coding a super simple server side markdown to html converter. So far code looks like this:

```
// markdown-to-html.ts

import { unified } from 'unified'
import markdown from 'remark-parse'
import remark2rehype from 'remark-rehype'
import html from 'rehype-stringify'

export async function markdownToHtml(markdownString: string) {
    const result = await unified()
        .use(markdown)
        .use(remark2rehype)
        .use(html)
        .process(markdownString)

    const htmlString = result.toString()

    return htmlString
}
```

How can I add code highlighting with Shiki library to this converter function?

I am not exactly sure how to use Shiki to address only the  html tags, and not the whole html input.